# Qt C++ QToolBox: How to add checkbox/button to title

Tags: c++, qt, button, checkbox, signals-slots

I would like to add checkbox or button into the toolbox's title and if it's checked then some action should be done (SINGAL - SLOT?). Is this possible or there is some other widget which provides that ability?

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, QToolBox doesn't support adding widgets to titles. A title can only contain a text.

However QToolBox is easy to implement. Just add QVBoxLayout, put titlebars and widgets in it. Then use titlebar's onclick events to call `setVisible()` on widgets to hide or show it. You may need to create separate form for titlebar, put your buttons inside it and reimplement `QWidget::mousePressEvent` to catch clicks. Then promote the main form's titlebar widgets to this class.

Answer (score -1):

create a QAction, make it checkable `setCheckable(true)` and connect to the toggled signal. it's not a checkbox but a button with the same behaviour. than add this action to the toolbox.

Comment: How to do this if I have created few tabs in Qt Creator's Designer and I want to point them to some action?

Comment: @WoJo I think you mixed up QToolBox and QToolBar.